# Python - parsing string to json

Tags: python, json, string, user-input

I'm trying to get a user input and from that create a json object and sent it through a tcp socket.. but I am sending a wrong json object beacuse the server can't deserialize it (but it works if I send the json directly from the code.
Here is my code:

```
import socket
import json

TCP_IP = '132.72.213.108'
TCP_PORT = 6666
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
typeText = raw_input("Enter the type: ")
argumentsText = raw_input("Enter arguments: ")
while (typeText != "end"):
  argumentsText = argumentsText.replace(",","\",\"");
  argumentsText = "\"" + argumentsText + "\""
  data = '{"type":'+typeText+',"parameters":['+argumentsText+']}'
  print(str({'type':typeText,'parameters':[argumentsText]}))
  s.send(json.dumps(data))
  result = json.loads(s.recv(1024))
  print("received: " + str(result)+"\n")
  typeText = raw_input("Enter the type: ")
  argumentsText = raw_input("Enter arguments: ")
s.close()
```

Comment: The question is not very clear, what are you asking? Can you provide a more condensed example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert str value (looking like a JSON) into JSON string.

`json.dumps` is to convert Python variables like a dictionary, into JSON string.

```
dct = {}
dct["a"] = "Ahahaha"
dct["b"] = 3.14

import json

print json.dumps(dct)
```

So for your case:

1. first create valid data structure (like dictionary) with the data you are going to send out
2. then use `json.dumps` to convert it to real JSON string and send it out.

Comment: Ohhh right!! just needed to send the data as-is.. Thanks!

Comment: @JaviDorfsman Yes, sending your already prepared JSON string is also an option. But if you rewrite it to `json.dumps`, your code will become far more readable and reliable.